# Finding inverse of $f(x) =\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$

Tags: functions, inverse, lambert-w

How do you find the inverse of the following function $$f(x) = \frac{\ln (x)}{x}$$

What looked like a simple question made my head hurt during exam.

Comment: Maybe that is because the inverse is non-elementary? What course was this? Were you supposed to find an expression for the inverse or the domain where it had an inverse or something like that?

Comment: You might wish to read about [Lambert's W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Are you sure you didn't misread it to find the integral, instead? Because that has a nice happy convenient form.

Comment: No I'm sure I read the question correctly. This was on HL IB mocks.

Comment: While it's always possible the examiners made a mistake, I suspect it's likely that the actual question didn't require you to **find** an inverse.  Perhaps it asked whether there **exists** an inverse (for the function defined on $(0,\infty)$) - the answer is no, $f$ is not one-to-one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Lambert's W-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) $$ xy = \ln y \Rightarrow e^{xy} = y \Rightarrow -xye^{-xy} = -x \Rightarrow W(-x) = -yx \Rightarrow y = -\frac{W(-x)}{x} $$